AR/VR inside Autodesk forge viewer
I'm working on a project where we aim to enhance the visualization capabilities of Autodesk Forge Viewer by adding AR/VR features. ResolveBIM serves as a reference for the kind of functionality we'd like to implement. Specifically, we're interested in features such as:
Overlaying BIM models onto real-world environments in AR.
Immersive VR experiences for exploring 3D models.
Interactive elements and annotations in AR/VR environments.
Specific Questions:
What are the key components and technologies required to integrate AR/VR functionality into Autodesk Forge Viewer?
Are there any specific APIs, SDKs, or libraries that are recommended for implementing AR/VR features in Autodesk Forge Viewer?
How can we handle the rendering and interaction aspects of AR/VR content within the Forge Viewer environment?
Are there any best practices or considerations we should keep in mind when designing and implementing AR/VR functionality in conjunction with Autodesk Forge Viewer
Can anyone provide insights or resources on how ResolveBIM achieved its AR/VR capabilities within the Autodesk Forge ecosystem?

It's a big task. I would reach out to ResolveVR to understand their new Wellington Engine.
In the meantime, we provide a simple sample that might help you explore the complexity of the task...
Go to aps.autodesk.com -> Code Samples (in the footer) -> Unity Example
The Repo has more details:
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-unity-poc

What about the VR extension provided for the autodesk viewer "Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR" is this still valid ?

That plugin is based on a very old webVR spec.  This was updated to webXR but was never released due to performance limitations and extensive support requirements.
Until Autodesk upgrades LMV to latest three.js (it’s stuck on R71), that extension is probably not worth your efforts.
